# Как заставить работать constexpr с указателем на -1?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

Нужен указатель на адрес 0xFFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF, или на -1. Пытаюсь определить как `constexpr auto hInvd = reinterpret_cast<void*>(-1ul);`, но вываливается ошибка, что это не константное выражение. Очевидно из-за reinterpret_cast. К сожалению, другие *_cast тоже не дают ничего полезного. Простой const работает без проблем `const auto hInvd=reinterpret_cast<void*>(-1ul);`
Мне нужен указатель на область памяти, которая будет свободна. nullptr для этого не годится, так как нулевой адрес может быть использован, а вот вероятность использования адреса 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF практически равна нулю.

Comment: Что если кастить уже по месту использования?

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalyan, тогда ругается, что изначальное выражение не constexpr

Comment: Т.е. используется тоже в constexpr где-то?

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalyan, нужно изначальное constexpr, чтобы можно было в дальнейшем производные constexpr делать.

Comment: Используйте `const`, с `constexpr` ничего не выйдет.

Comment: @ixSci, непонятно почему не работает. -1 есть константа.

Comment: Потому что `reinterpret_cast` запрещён для `constexpr`. Указатель на `constexpr` данные должен указывать на `constexpr` данные. Очевидно, что по случайному адресу `0xFFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF` никаких данных нет.

Comment: @ixSci, откуда знать есть там данные или нет? Адрес каноничен.

Comment: Неоткуда, поэтому он и не может является `constexpr`. Если бы Вы имели нормальный указатель на `constexpr` данные, то никакого преобразование не потребовалось бы. А раз не имеет, то как язык может верить непонятному преобразованию?

Comment: @ixSci, по адресу 0х401000 есть данные, но и этот указатель нельзя использовать.

Comment: Почему бы просто nullptr не использовать? Там, где нулевой адрес используется, его значение не будет равно нулю.

Comment: @Afokenai, Вы не понимаете, я же написал _по случайному_. Вы не можете превратить число в указатель на `constexpr`, т.к. это прямо запрещено стандартном языка. Я просто попытался Вам пояснить, почему так происходит, т.е. какова причина такого запрета.

Comment: *"Мне нужен указатель на область памяти, которая будет свободна."* - `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` не является таким указателем. Кроме того, было бы хорошо привести какой-нибудь контекст, а то так это похоже на проблему XY.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Конвертировать любую целочисленную константу в указатель на `constexpr` невозможно, т.к. для этого используется `reinterpet_cast`, который прямо запрещён в описании константных выражений ([[expr.const]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const)).

Почему так? Потому что `constexpr` всегда является чем-то определённым и не может дать на выходе неопределённое поведение. Если бы можно было случайный адрес привести к указателю на `constexpr`, тогда получилось бы, что его использование (разыменовывание) может приводить к UB.

Comment: Ну если постараться, то gcc сожрал :)

Comment: *"не может дать на выходе неопределённое поведение"* - а как на счет `constexpr int foo(int x) { return x++ + ++x; }`

Comment: @VTT, попробуйте вызвать в `constexpr` контексте.

Comment: Вызывается, печатает 6. Хотя предупреждение выдается, это да.

Comment: @VTT, значит это баг. Можно смело репортить

Comment: @VTT, единственно, что я могу предположить, почему это может не быть багом, это то, что UB происходит внутри функции, делая всю программу невалидной и они не заморачиваются на дополнительную диагностику, т.к. всё равно UB. Хотя всё равно странно.

Comment: @VTT, похожий [вопрос на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319413/why-do-constant-expressions-have-an-exclusion-for-undefined-behavior); всё-таки я склоняюсь к багу в компиляторах (всех).

Answer (score 4):

> ## Как выяснилось, этот ответ - баг компилятора :)

Ну, gcc сожрал финт с вычитанием единицы из нулевого указателя, правда, только через промежуточную переменную: https://ideone.com/Hp6DNt

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  constexpr void *p = nullptr;
  constexpr void *res = p - 1;

  cout << res << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Так лучше в [bug tracker](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/), а не в ответ.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82226/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-ixsci).